# Navigation Drawer Issue

Tags: android

I'm following the example at android developers http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.

when I reach to:

```
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

Its says that ic_drawer cannot be resolved, the same with string drawer open and close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add png image named `ic_drawer` in drawable folder. And add strings in `strings.xml`

Comment: REally?? i thought they were using system resources..omg so sorry